# limit background position in css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to specify a y position of background as ‘center’ and at the same time set for it a limit, so that the actual y position doesn't go over some certain value?

Let's say image height is 50px. We set the limit to 25px. In case container's height is 70px then background y position is 10px. Container expands to 100px and background image positioned vertically at 25px. Container expands further to 150px, background y position remains the same which is 25px.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do this using only CSS. You might be able to achieve it using javascript.

Comment: You lost me at hello. Could you try to explain this by telling us what you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: He want a mix of relative and absolute background image positioning. And sorry, this is not possible with just CSS. I guess, this not even possible with CSS3. You'll need a small javascript which checks the height of your container and sets a new css class if your limit is reached.

Comment: @Val how about the js solution given below? Or do you want to avoid any js???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `image sprite`

Refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: I don't think so. An example would be nice to back your statement up!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/jfPP3/ (have fun changing the height of the container in the css)

```
var limit = 25; // you define your limit here
var container = document.getElementById('contain1');
var image = document.getElementById('img1');
var y = Math.round((container.offsetHeight - image.offsetHeight)/2);
if(y > limit){
    y = limit;
}
image.style.top= y + 'px';
```

Simply define a limit, get the height of the contain and the image, and check the resulting `y` with your limit. Finally define the position of your image.

In my example, I put my image as `position:absolute`, but you could also simply change the `top-margin` of your image.